# 'Dummy' LaTeX environment

Tags: compiling, environments, comments

I have a big LaTeX file which I would like to compile so that certain environments like `figure` are not shown. To that end I wanted to make use of the `renewenvironment` command. But the facilities of this command are rather limited: essentially, one can only replace an environment by something which is logically also an environment. What would suffice for me, hence, is to introduce a 'dummy enviroment' - one which discards the argument. Is there any way to define it?

EDIT: I also need to eliminate the `displaymath` environment. This might be essential, because the argument of it is not going to be valid text on its own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using something like:

```
\usepackage{comment}
\renewenvironment{displaymath}{}{}
\excludecomment{displaymath}
```

For more details read the TeX FAQ on [Conditional compilation](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-conditional).

Comment: +1. Use the `comment` package, Luke...

Comment: This seems to answer my question as I posed it, but, unfortunately, I am failing to apply this solution to resolve my original problem. In particular, I need to eliminate all the 'displaymath' environments, but neither '\renewenvironment{displaymath}{\comment\\[}{\\]\endcomment}' nor '\let\displaymath=\comment  \let\enddisplaymath=\endcomment' work indeed. First one fails because \comment starts working right away before being substituted; the second one fails because the content of 'displaymath' is ill-formed unless put into math environment.

Comment: \usepackage{comment}
\renewenvironment{displaymath}{}{}
\excludecomment{displaymath}

Comment: Ulrike, thanks for your very good answer. Hope you don't mind I made some small edits to improve it and make it a [great answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/quality-standards-for-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The `draft` option with many document classes will leave blank spaces where your pictures should be. Otherwise using the [`ifdraft`](http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=ifdraft) package and wrapping your figures in the following might be an option:

```
\ifdraft{}{FIGURE CODE}
```

This should cause the figures not to appear if your document class calls the `draft` option. (Or put something like `FIGURE GOES HERE` in the first set of curly braces to have that text appear in drafts.