# Environment for NOT compiling things

Tags: environments, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ['Dummy' LaTeX environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/dummy-latex-environment)

Since the explanation why on earth I need this is longer than the actual question, I begin with the latter. I would like to define an environment which has the effect that everything inside it is NOT compiled. Ideally it should be just an equivalent of commenting out everything inside; I prefer not to use frame constructions or other floats (because they mess up footnotes).

Now for the reason behind it, in case anyone cares: When writing a proof, I prefer to put every single detail in so at least I can be sure the proof is 99.9% correct once I have proofread it. Unsurprisingly, this leads to extreme bloating and I don't feel like putting pages of trivial induction bases and straightforward computations on arXiv. So I make two versions of my texts: one for verification and completeness, one for readability and publication. However, when a typo is spotted or some simplification is found, I am forced to edit *both* of them and to manually fine-tune things. I'd prefer to minimize this work. The obvious idea is to maintain both versions in one TeX file. Compiling each of them is then a matter of switching the semantics of one environment to "ignore" and of the other to "compile".

Comment: The top voted answer (which is better in this case than the accepted answer) to this question: [Latex tag for making a comment appear or disappear in pdf?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3023/2693) should help.

Comment: Or see ['Dummy' LaTeX environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3020/2975). Anyway the `comment` package is the way to go.

Comment: Please take a look at the linked questions as the answers there might help you. If they do, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find the answers quickly. If they don't, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: Thanks, this seems perfect! I should have thought about the Linked Questions. Thing is, while I was writing my post, the system showed me some linked questions which had nothing to do with what I want, so I didn't expect that the post-submission Linked Questions would be of any use.

Comment: No problem, this is a good duplicate. The "post-submission Linked Questions" are there because of the links in the above comments. Thanks for letting us know that it helped you. I closed it as a duplicate now.