# How to replace a command with a dummy one?

Tags: macros, errors, optional-arguments, technical-environment

On the question [How to create a dummy generic environment replacement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387389/how-to-create-a-dummy-generic-environment-replacement) I learned how to replace an generic envinronment with a dummy one. Until now I had success replacing then as replacing `\currenttime` from `datetime` package with `\def\currenttime{Current Time}`.

But when I tried this strategy with `\includegraphics`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\newif\ifdebug
\debugtrue
% \debugfalse

\ifdebug
    % \def\includegraphics{includegraphics}
    \newcommand{\includegraphics}{includegraphics}
\else\fi

\begin{document}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictures/ex01}

\end{document}
```

It does not worked:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   ]
l.86     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                                           {pictures/ex01}
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   ]
l.86     \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]
                                           {pictures/ex01}
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

Can I wrap the command contents as `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictures/ex01}` on verbatim environment as done for environments?

```
\@ifundefined{longtable}
{
    \newenvironment{longtable}[0]
        {longtable environment \par\verbatim\tiny}
        {\endverbatim\endgraf\normalfont replacement for debug mode}
}{}
```

---

## Update

Trying to do:

```
\newcommand{\includegraphics}[2]{\par\verbatim\tiny includegraphics #1 #2 \endverbatim\endgraf\normalfont}
```

Throws a new error:

```
File: t1cmtt.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
Runaway argument?
! Paragraph ended before \next was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.87 

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

But it is printing something on the PDF:

[image]

---

Related:

1. ['Dummy' LaTeX environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3020/dummy-latex-environment)
2. [More than one optional argument for newcommand](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29973/more-than-one-optional-argument-for-newcommand)
3. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros

Comment: Why not just pass the `draft` or `demo` option to `graphicx`?

Comment: My idea is not to load it, only treat its instructions as plain text or perhaps hide it.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: You need to handle the arguments, e.g. with `\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{....}`

Comment: You are missing the default for the optional argument.  Not`[2]` but `[2][]`. And don't use verbatim here, it doesn't make much sense. `\detokenize{#2}` is better.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, its magic! I used `\newcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{ includegraphics \detokenize{#1} \detokenize{#2} }` and it worked.

Comment: @Alan Munn, if using `draft` or `demo` option to graphicx does the same thing, I would just look into their implementation and copy it. Also, now I can do it for any package command, whether they support `draft` or `demo` option or not. Perhaps my question title was misleading. I will change it to `How to replace a command with a dummy one?`

Comment: Don't believe that you can use the same dummy for everything. In general you need to have an idea about the type of arguments a command can receive to write a good dummy command.

Comment: So perhaps other commands can have a little different signature, but I think can be learned its difference and the same ideia applied here used on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this??

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newif\ifdebug
\debugtrue
% \debugfalse

\ifdebug
    \renewcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\detokenize{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\else\fi

\begin{document}
\sloppy% can be used to avoid overfull boxes

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictures/ex01}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictures/long-directory-name/ex01}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I would not include `graphicx`, I would use  `\@ifundefined{includegraphics}{\newcommand{\includegraphics}...}{}` instead of `\renewcommand{\includegraphics}`. This should be useful when I am disabling packages to find out incompatibilities.

Comment: @user how about `\ifdebug
    \newcommand{\includegraphics}[2][]{\detokenize{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}
\else
  \usepackage{graphicx}
\fi`

Comment: Basically, it is what I am doing, but for now I manually disable the `\usepackage{graphicx}` and set the `\ifdebugtrue`.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a job of `xparse` ;-)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newif\ifdebug
\debugtrue
% \debugfalse

\ifdebug
  \RenewDocumentCommand\includegraphics{s+O{}om}{includegraphics}
\else\fi

\begin{document}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pictures/ex01}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `+O{}`? `som` suffices

Comment: @egreg Original `graphics` syntax allows two optional arguments, and one (probably) needs to allow for `\par` tokens in keys (someone is bound to do that): on the `O{}` I was allowing for not needing a `NoValue` test if passing to key setting (so one only needs to check `#3`).